# Infering generic types in typescript

Tags: typescript, type-inference

I am trying to wrap my head around infering generics in Typescript, but I can't seem to get a hold on what am I doing wrong. My concrete example would be rather large to leave here, but I've made a small typescript playground link, which illustrates the problem I am facing completely.

Here's the [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBGCGIBsD2sAmAVc0C8UDeAUFMVANoDWEIAXAM7ABOAlgHYDmAutVPc%20wQF8CBUJB6QAxkwBmTCQAV4yNACEouQiSixuvVm0HDR0WpJlzFiFKgDC6-ERI6ejfQBpHxAEa7X-IQQSCLC0tFAAggA86JbKqFAQAB7AECyoYXBWaJhiuLAsIAB8%20EJBIWEq0bHWCcmp6eIQUrIKStZquKZN5q1ZqCrFSSlpYVExbWjFeKXBoVB2Q-UVkV3NFhO2UwHGUACSLNIQDADSVLTRORDFuOiXtcMNUayHDFCnILTFAPxvZ1DcLAgADcjgBuQKzMKLNJHSKeW5Ye5LCIeEjod5hXD7F4Yi5YQoELbCaQAVxYEmATCQLCgbAgwBskOijPKSJGEUKAAoAJTcaGoWHoFmhKaeKAMekkhg0wEAdzZAoYzMhXO54ICBAA9AAqbVQWUACxAUCYYWABtN4sl0v0UHN0B2ISgACJ%20bDKqsetVVIU3DANpdCs6TSx6BA0FAkNIQy9bc7PS1vf1g077TwmtT4nTAcwJD9tZqCAh6XaIPQAKJ1GEMDq0%20nC84DHngrW6-VGk1mi1hCXAKUsW1px1hV1VxWRGx%20zJxQPB1hhiNRmNHOMJ9Z9GwprsmDNpOs5uT5wvF4Clitjo52XB0hlMmyq8FAA)

Basically, I am trying to infer a generic parameter from a class hierarchy:

```
type payloadType = {
    [key:string]: string
}

type specificPayloadB = {
    a: string
}

type specificPayloadC = {
    a: string,
    b: string
}

class A<TPayload extends payloadType = any> {}
class B<TPayload extends specificPayloadB = specificPayloadB> extends A<TPayload> {}
class C extends B<specificPayloadC> {}

type InferKeys<TType> = TType extends A<infer Keys> ? Keys : never;
class extender<
   TType extends A,
   TKeys = InferKeys<TType>
> {}

function getClass<TClass extends A>(): extender<TClass> {
    return new extender<TClass>();
}

let testExtenderB = getClass<B>();
let testExtenderC = getClass<C>();
```

The above example, gives no compilation error, but when inspecting the returned variable types with typescript, `testExtenderB` is identified as a `extender<B<specificPayloadB>, payloadType>` which is correct, but based on the information provided, it could be more correctly identified as a `extender<B<specificPayloadB>, specificPayloadB>`.

The same is true in my opinion for the `testExtenderC` variable, which is identified as `extender<C, payloadType>` instead of it being identified as `extender<C, specificPayloadC>`.

Am I doing something wrong here? Is it possible to achieve the correct identification of the variables, without explicitly providing the types to typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript has a structural type system. For object types this means the members of the type are important when determining type compatibility (see [FAQ](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-is-astring-assignable-to-anumber-for-interface-at--)). This means that unused type parameters are a not very significant in the type system. Since you don't use `TPayload` in `A` the type parameter doesn't have any significance in the type system, so during inference it will end up with it's default value in some cases.

If you add a member, inference works as you expect it to:

```
class A<TPayload extends payloadType = any> { p!: TPayload }
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=1&pln=12&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBGCGIBsD2sAmAVc0C8UDeAUFMVANoDWEIAXAM7ABOAlgHYDmAutVPc+wQF8CBUJB6QAxkwBmTCQAV4yNACEouQiSixuvVm0HDR0WpJlzFiFKgDC6-ERI6ejfQBpHxAEa7X-IQQSCLC0tFAAggA86JbKqFAQAB7AECyoYXBWaJhiuLAsIAB8+DAAhNwxStZQQkEhYSrRsdVJKWlhphBSsgpVqvad3RZ9qCrFranpEU0jxXi1waFQdhPtUI2D5r1ZtnMBxlAAkizSEAwA0lS00TkQxbjotwnJk2FRrKcMUJcgtMUA-N8rlBuCwIAA3M4AbkCizCq1QZ0inkeWGebSm4Q8JHQPzCuGOnzxNywhQIe2E0gAriwJMAmEgWFA2BBgDY4dF2fV0a8IoUABQASm4CKR6C5oTmnigDFZVIYTLBAHceWkxRK-kKYUIEKyoCB7MrVYiGJExlrhAB6ABU1uNSI2Zh6zVUhTc4i6Wxdo2K1stBF1wCgKXoAFEXmqGGpcCy2RzzYKYQQbXaQ8BwxizjYRRGTZEbO7Ns6RjZff7A8GIGHc1n7LGNfmBYmCEA)

Comment: Does this mean that I need to actually define that variable somewhere along the lines, or just plain and simply add it, and leave it undefined if I never intend to use it for anything else? I am unfammiliar with the `!` exclamation mark notation, could you please explain what it does?

Comment: You can leave it undefined It just need to be a member in the class. The `!` is there to tell the compiler not to complain that the value is not assigned in the initialization or in the constructor