# Typescript Generics: Inferring Generics in sub levels

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, inferred-type

I have several types that I am working with that I would like to have inferred at the method call level.

```
class AbstractModal<TInput, TOutput> {
...
}

type Constructor<T> = new(...args: any[]) => T;

function openModal<TConstructor extends Constructor<AbstractModal<?, ?>>>(
    ctor: TConstructor,
    initialState?: TInput // TInput type for Constructor of Abstract Modal
): TOutput {
...
}
```

What I would like to be able to do is have a class defined as:

```
class TestModalType extends AbstractModal<string /*or another type*/, number /*or another type*/> {
...
}
```

and be able to call `openModal` with `TestModalType` as the generic parameter with the compiler getting upset at me for improper inputs on the initial call.

I have tried reading into these questions but have not found any help:

[Typescript strict typing and inferred generic types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76302746/typescript-strict-typing-and-inferred-generic-types-propagated)

[Inferring generic types in typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70667824/infering-generic-types-in-typescript)

The specific problem that I am finding is that a lot of these answers are written for generics with only one generic parameter, where my situation requires a much more in depth example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably better off drilling into the type you need from `TConstructor`, but in order to do that you need to know how `TInput` and `TOutput` are used.

So let's you start with this:

```
class AbstractModal<TInput, TOutput> {
  open(input: TInput) {
    return {} as TOutput // logic here
  }
}
```

Now you know that `TInput` is used as the first parameter to `open()` and `TOutput` is the return type of `open()`.

Now you can write `openModal` like this:

```
function openModal<
  TConstructor extends Constructor<AbstractModal<unknown, unknown>>
>(
  ctor: TConstructor,
  initialState?: Parameters<InstanceType<TConstructor>['open']>[0],
): ReturnType<InstanceType<TConstructor>['open']> {
  return {} as any
}
```

- `TConstructor extends Constructor<AbstractModal<unknown, unknown>>` constrains `TConstructor` to a `Constructor` that returns `AbstractModal<unknown, unknown>`. These `unknown`s will be made more specific by the `extends` when this is called.
- `Parameters<InstanceType<TConstructor>['open']>[0]` gets the `open` method form the instance type that the constructor return, and uses the type of the first parameter.
- `ReturnType<InstanceType<TConstructor>['open']>` gets the `open` method from the instance type that the constructor returns, and uses the return type.

And now this should work:

```
class TestModalType extends AbstractModal<string, number> {
  //...
}

const res1 = openModal(TestModalType, 'a string')
//    ^ number
```

---

Alternatively, if you want to `infer` the generics directly, you can do that, but it's quite a bit more verbose and cryptic. To do that you have to use a conditional type like:

```
A extends B<infer C> ? C : never
```

That might look like this:

```
function openModalInfer<TConstructor extends Constructor<TestModalType>>(
  ctor: TConstructor,
  initialState?: TConstructor extends Constructor<
    AbstractModal<infer TInput, unknown>
  > ? TInput : never,
): TConstructor extends Constructor<
    AbstractModal<unknown, infer TOutput>
  > ? TOutput : never {
  return {} as any
}

const res2 = openModalInfer(TestModalType, 'a string')
//    number
```

[See Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.8.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6oDwAqAfFALxQIQDuUAFAHSMCGqA5kgFxRMIgDaAXQCUZEgQBQ4zABsmSJFACCAIxSom2ALJwAJk2mEAkgjDpgAGigEA8mdPASAb3FQocSAloBLE2a4FjexFnV1dUCGB0VAQoRwBfbgUbOzMXKDjxDKlZeSsIFG09aQJwaAgAD2AIBB0FFTUNYEL9PDUfVksEdABbZQhUJzSAeiHGekzJADN0BGwvRDcPZoM0gnhkNCwcVCgKqpqFdbUt3Dx6tEblvBmAawQ4KgRLW-vHoiJxIlo07Fx-I82v1Q5jSPi8wC8+gAysAmFUAPxcAAKLCY3Qi-SQeGMKB4mAgJUghABGCBRD4AHJ3NUKQJyQAGAQgoRcABKESiCEJEGxGzxBNKxMQxzJlOpCFpgzCHOisQScm4vAmUmFwCg4SQAEYyItqstaAR8k1dPpuZYKUwoG0EKwKUJxCNQlAAHrwySOgC0XqmMzmC3Fy2Mk36eFWJJOOz21VqsFVpO2Z1UFy0JoMLweTyg6beHy+P22-zjEZBrjBEOhsIRhY28dwu0q0cORaBoad53UKaKeB8wZ2AV8FizCDuGY+rhI8KsgTMUC4lAAbv1mdWRdt6-sY+GW2lXO3LqnrsPXpme-0rLZgPYx1AJ+eUmq5xBFzsQuqZTF4olFSBlZhVW+kAAJh1ANUyDfoDSNZYzSgC0rTQdo7QdIYnVdcQgA)

Comment: Thank you so much for the very clear explanation! It took me a minute to figure out the correct implementation for my use case but now that I have I love it!